# "Что такое осень" - синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Что такое осень - это небо, Плачущее небо под ногами...

А как сделать разбор предложения "Что такое осень"? Чем является местоимение "такое"?

Comment: Вера, если бы не местоимение ''Что'' ,я бы предположил, что указательное местоимение ''такой'' является здесь частью именного сказуемого, где пропущена связка ''есть''. Ну тогда остается вопрос: чем является ''что''?

Comment: См также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439687/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8c/439688#439688

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Осень* - подлежащее, устойчивое выражение *что такое* - составное именное сказуемое с нулевой связкой. Если заменить  местоимения существительным и прилагательным, получаем примерно такой макет: Счастье великое - дети. Устойчивое выражение *что такое* можно заменить и одним словом. Тире в Вашем примере не ставится, так как сказуемое *что такое* содержит вопросительное местоимение *что?***

§ 15. Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится:

1. Если подлежащее выражено личным или указательным местоимением: Она его дочь. Он хочет понять ее (Щерб.); Это кабинет? Это спальня? (Ч.)...
2. Если один из главных членов выражен вопросительным местоимением, а другой — существительным или личным местоимением: Кто ваш защитник? *Что такое учеба?* Кто она? [Справочник Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=52)

Comment: Наверное, можно назвать "что такое" словосочетанием в роли именной части сказуемого с пропущенной связкой.  А в встречаются  в грамматике такие сочетания местоименного прилагательного и существительного, или это прецедент?  И какова семантика этого сочетания, в  чем разница между предложениями: Это что? Это что такое? (А про тире речи не было, откуда ему там взяться).

Comment: Довольно часто встречается. "Цуцик этакий"(Ч.),"Что это за проказник такой этот барин!", "У квартального только один сын был, да дурачок такой".

Comment: "Это что?" - требует конкретного названия предмета или явления. "Это что такое?" -  кроме того, содержит неопределённую оценку (зависит от контекста). Тире я оговорила, так как привела пример с тире. Это не для Вас, а для школьников).

Comment: 1) В ваших примерах "такой" относится к существительным, а не к местоимениям: такой проказник, такой дурачок. 2) На столе лежит неизвестный предмет. Вы можете спросить: "это что?"  или "это что такое?". Какая разница между этими вопросами?

Comment: Ekaterina,а где подлежащее и сказуемое в предложении "Что это за проказник такой этот барин!" ? Если убрать ''такой этот барин'' , то с подлежащим и сказуемым все ясно: что за проказник - сказуемое , это - подлежащее. А как быть со всем предложением?

Comment: Вера, Вы просили примеры - "сочетания местоименного прилагательного и существительного". Что-то не так поняла? Насчет слова "такое". В этом слове уже есть, повторюсь, определение-оценка, хоть и неясная без контекста.

Comment: Серж, не портите красивое предложение. Ещё одно указательное местоимение? Да ещё и тавтология? Помилуйте! Придумайте что-нибудь другое и оформите в виде вопроса. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Екатерина, вы считаете, что в предложении ''Что это за проказник!'' - тавтология?

Comment: Серж, мне кажется, что основная часть  предложения следующая:  этот барин такой проказник, всё остальное, включая инверсию, для красоты слога.  Выражение "что это за" выражает эмоциональную оценку явления (восхищение, возмущение и т.п.): Что за манера!

Comment: Вера, в предложении " Что это за проказник" - подлежащее "это"  - "что за" - сказуемое.

Answer (score 1):

Как я думаю.

1) Это что? Нас интересует только название предмета.

Это что такое? Нас интересует не только название, но и описание предмета (сходство с другими предметами, особые качества).

В этих примерах "что такое" - сочетание в роли именной части сказуемого, связка пропущена.

2) Что такое осень. Нельзя сказать: что осень? Нужна обязательная связка (что есть осень?) или обязательное сочетание "что такое" в роли сказуемого. Здесь предмет уже назван, поэтому переходим к его описанию.

Comment: Да, Вера, я с вами согласен!