# Синтаксический разбор предложения "Что такое жизнь?"

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Что такое жизнь?

В этом предложении местоимение "такое" будет в роли глагольной связки?

Comment: Похожий вопрос  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416547/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жизнь  (есть) **что такое**?

"***Что такое***"  —     местоименное сочетание в роли именной части составного именного сказуемого, связка  ***есть*** пропущена.